# Explanation/Reference request for necessary and sufficent conditions for polynomial roots to lie inside unit circle

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, roots, time-series

In the book Applied Econometric Time Series by Walter Enders (third edition, page 30) there is a discussion about the characteristic polynomial of the homogeneous part of an n-th order difference (recurrence) equation. In the discussion, one necessary and one sufficient condition for roots of the polynomial

$$\alpha^{n} - a_{1}\alpha^{n-1} - a_{2}\alpha^{n-2}... - a_{n}$$

to lie inside the unit circle (roots are allowed to be complex, so roots with magnitude less than 1) are presented.

Put differently, we seek the values of $\alpha$ that solve

$$\alpha^{n} - a_{1}\alpha^{n-1} - a_{2}\alpha^{n-2}... - a_{n} = 0,$$

and the claims are as follows:

1. In an n-th order equation, a necessary condition for all characteristic roots to lie inside the unit circle is $$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} < 1.$$
2. Since the values of the $a_{i}$ can be positive or negative, a sufficient condition for all characteristic roots to lie inside the unit circle is $$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} |a_{i}| < 1.$$

I would very much appreciate references or explanations that prove the claims. I have tried to see if I could show the claims directly by symbol manipulations and using the assumptions in the claims, but I have not tried using any general theorems. I am not very knowledgeable about polynomials in general (which might be obvious from this post), so I realize that I might not possess the necessary mathematical machinery to understand these claims. Thank you in advance to anyone that took the time to read this post.

**Edit:** The answer from Hagen von Eitzen below helped me understand (2) and  partly (1). However, I still haven't understood (1) completely. Perhaps I have used his hint differently than intended. My confusion is outlined in a comment below his reply.

Comment: Are the $\alpha_i$ real ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the $a_{i}$ are real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1.: Intermediate value theorm on $[1,\infty)$

For 2.: triangle inequality for $|\alpha|=|a_1+\alpha^{-1}a_2+\cdots|$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now get (2) and much of (1). One question remains: I was able to show (1) for polynomials with real roots. How does this hint apply to the case of complex roots? 

For real roots I argued that given that all real roots are in the unit interval, it follows by the IVT that the polynomial must be positive for all $\alpha \geq 1$ or negative for all $\alpha \geq 1$. Since the polynomial is positive for large enough $\alpha$, it follows that it must be positive, and hence for $\alpha = 1$ we get $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} < 1.$

Comment: Nevermind my concern in the first comment. If we assume that all roots are inside the unit circle, then in particular there are no real roots in $[1, \infty)$, and by the above argument that of course implies that the sum in question is less than $1$.